# Printer issue on Ubuntu 14.04 - Canon IP2770

Tags: 14.04, printing

How can I add a **Canon IP2770** printer on Ubuntu 14.04? I've already tried using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-ip2700series
```

But I receive an error message saying:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
one@God:~$ sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-ip2700series
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cnijfilter-ip2700series
```

Answer (score 2):

I installed the printer using these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
sudo apt-get update
```

then installed libtiff4 library on my 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 using these commands:

```
wget http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tiff3/libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

After installing the libtiff4 library, install the printer driver using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-ip2700series
```

After rebooting, you can add the printer.

If you are using a 32-bit operating system, use these commands to install libtiff4 library:

```
wget http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tiff3/libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: see [How do I install libtiff.so.3?](//askubuntu.com/q/44132) for a workaround to try before you downgrade libtiff like this - it might not work, but if it does it's better & safer as it won't break other applications