# Printer works fine; refuses to print duplex

Tags: canon, duplex-printing

I've just reinstalled my Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (ah, much better!). 
My **Canon MG5350** can **print duplex** and I used this all the time on the old installation, just to save paper. But now it won't anymore and I can't figure out why.

1. The printer is connected via USB and Ubuntu found drivers for it automatically. The test page went well.
2. Then I went into printer properties > printer options > ink type = Black and made another test print. That also worked well.
3. Then I went into printer properties > **printer options > 2-sided printing = long edge (standard)**. The test print is submitted, and the printer briefly wakes up, but then the job is gone from the queue without it being printed.
4. When I reset **2-sided printing to "off"**, the test print works again.
    
   It's the same result when I want to print from a program (tested with a PDF file):
5. **1-sided works** (as per the configured default) when I use the system dialog to print.
6. **2-sided fails** when I use the system dialog and choose 2-sided printing (overriding the printer default). Same as in step 3 above = no print.

Given that this used to work on my previous Ubuntu installation, I know that I am not asking for the impossible here. Something about that 2-sided option is awry but I lack the printer configuration knowledge to find it.

Update: I know one thing that doesn't work: [This old answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/135245/5786) links to [this manual installation guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/124284/5786), but when I submit a test page after completing that guide, the page is added to the printer queue (in Ubuntu) but the (physical) printer never notices this, so the job just sits there forever.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found [this solution](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/12/canon-driver-scangear-mp-ubuntu-14-04/) that works for me. Basically, these are the required steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:inameiname/stable
sudo apt-get -y install cnijfilter-common-64 cnijfilter-mg5300series-64
```

I honestly don't know what that repository is or why that one works better than the one provided with Ubuntu. I just see that this works better than anything else I've tried so far.

I also note that the PPA from `michael-gruz/canon` ([mentioned here](https://askubuntu.com/q/575394/5786) for example) doesn't seem to work with 14.04 (anymore?).