# Colors wrong when printing on photo paper

Tags: printing, canon, photo

I've just reinstalled Ubuntu and also [reinstalled my printer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741162/printer-works-fine-refuses-to-print-duplex) - which used to work just fine before I reinstalled (was necessary for other reasons).

When I now print images, I have to select `plain paper` to get a half-decent result. If I choose `glossy photo paper`, then the result is wrong: it almost looks like a negative image, but completely without blacks.

Below is a scan of two printouts I made. Identical image, identical printer settings except for the `plain`/`photo` paper setting.

This problem is not specific to the current printer driver. It was the same on the default Ubuntu printer driver.

What is going on here? How can I troubleshoot this?

[image]

Comment: Not a realy good solution but because of so many issues with photo-printing and Canon drivers I finally gave up and installed a spare Windows XP in Virtual Box only just for printing photos. Apart from that: one thing worth checking is to make sure the driver is set to RBG, not CMYK.

Comment: Thank you @Takkat, I tried RGB as well but it looked bad too - not like this, just very very much too dark. (I tried a lot of combinations of printer settings, and have a whole stack of photos to prove it.)